# I have a lot of repetition in my Vue.js code, how could I fix that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

So I only very recently started with the concept of Vue or React, JS libraries that are the view layer of your app. Now I started building a tiny little test app with Vue that has video lists, they're simply lists of videos. However, every video list has a different source from my own JSON API, so one list might request "api/v/1/related" (related videos for video with ID 1) and one might be a general "api/v/popular" for the most popular videos.

Now all these lists have the same HTML markup, it looks something like this:

```
<ul class="video-list" id="uniqueIdentifier-video-list">
    <li v-repeat="videos" class="row">
        <a href="#" class="image-wrapper">
            <div style="background: url('{{ thumbnail }}') center; background-size: cover;"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
            <h4>
                <a href="#">{{ title }}</a>
                <small>{{ length }}</small>
            </h4>
            <p class="video-description">{{ desc }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see me implementing Vue with  repeat, the videos are coming dynamically from a backend. You can see me grabbing the thumbnail, title, length and the description. I created a bunch of dummy videos that are returned by the API, an example video response looks like this in JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Cool example video",
  "desc": "This video is about very interesting things and such",
  "length": "0:25",
  "thumbnail": "https://unsplash.it/1280/720?image=50"
}
```

The HTML markup is the same on every page, so that's one point of repetition/code duplication, but the much mroe important one are the Vue instances.

So for each of these lists I have mostly the same behavior, the list is a Vue instance that is bound to the unique ID and it fetches the videos (using vue-resource), puts them in the videos property and that powers the list. It looks like this:

```
var uniqueVideoList = new Vue({
    el: '#uniqueIdentifier-video-list',

    data: {
        videos: []
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.fetchVideos();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchVideos: function() {
            this.$http.get('/api/v/popular', function(videos) {
                this.videos = videos;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Pretty much this exact code, the Vue instance, I have copied for each and every video list on the site. So I have the HTML markup and JavaScript copied for every instance, the HTML is the exact same and the JS is apart from the single endpoint it needs to hit.

What could I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Object Oriented Programming can fix this :)

Comment: Please do elaborate.

Comment: make a method that does that last bit of code, but with arguments/defaults replacing all the unique nouns (css selector, vid base url, etc)  to reduce it to one function call per list instead of a bunch of code. or consider using a special class instead of a specific id, move the base url to a data-attrib, and then scan onload for the right class, loop through results, and do the vue actions to each list by reading the config from the element itself; declarative.

Comment: I was thinking the Vue components might work, but I can't quite figure them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var VueCreator = function (id, endPoint) {
    var myVue = new Vue({
        el: id,

        data: {
            videos: []
        },

        ready: function() {
            this.fetchVideos();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchVideos: function() {
                this.$http.get(endPoint, function(videos) {
                    this.videos = videos;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return myVue;
}

//pseudo code, assumes videoList is an object that has each unique list with an id and an endpoint
var lists = [];
forEach(videoList, function(obj) {
    var tempList = new VueCreate(obj.id, obj.endPoint);
    lists.push(tempList);
})
```

A general rule in js (and maybe all of coding) is if you need to do something more than once, write a function to do it.